# Route config challenge with additional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have very simple question about Route configs in Web Api's.

My goal is to merge two methods into one.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("foo/bar")]
public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod()
{
    //TODO: Implement
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}



[HttpGet]
[Route("foo/bar/{element}")]
public HttpResponseMessage AnotherTestMethod(string element)
{
    //TODO: Implement
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Code pasted above works.

Of course, I've read some tutorials on customizing routes, however I did not succeed. The string element is optional one.

This is what I tried in RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "DefaultTestMethod", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PropertyDefinitions",
            url: "foo/bar/{element}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "TestMethod", element = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );         
    }
}
```

Thank You for any hint or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the default value for the `element`. And in route parameter declare the variable as nullable. This treats the parameter as optional.

```
[Route("foo/bar/{element?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod(string element = null)
```

Comment: Thank You! It was so easy :-).

Answer (score 0):

Why you not use only one method as the following .

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("foo/bar/{string element}")]
public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod(string element)
{
//TODO: Implement
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

As you known, no matter the parameter of element is set or not set, the TestMethod() will be called.

Comment: Thank you for help. However it does not work :-(. Or probably I don't see your point.